# Is it possible to define a function in terms of a power series?

Tags: function-construction

Is it at all possible to define a function in Mathematica in terms of a power series? For a specific example, I wish to write $x(\tau)$ as

$x(\tau)=x_{0}(\tau)+\mu x_{1}(\tau)+\mu^{2}x_{2}(\tau)+\cdots$

(I'm okay with truncating terms, as long as I can determine how many terms I keep.)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am looking to use these symbolically to plug into a differential equation and solve for each $x_i$ after grouping coefficients of powers of $\mu$. (Along with another power series $\omega = \omega_0 + \mu\omega_1+\mu^2\omega_2\cdots$ where each $\omega_i$ is constant.) It's important to note that each $x_i$ is a separate function of $\tau$, which is why the basic Mathematica tutorials I have seen have been of no help.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingPowerSeriesExpansions.html "Making Power Series Expansions"

Comment: Take a look at `Series`, `Sum`, `NSum` and possibly `SeriesCoefficient`.  It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but these might help.  You may want to clarify the question using a concrete example, and tell us if you're interested in numerical or symbolic calculations.

Comment: Sorry, I looking for symbolic calculations. I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: How do you compute those $x_i$ though?  Do you have a formula in terms of $i$?  Do you maybe have a recursive formula?  Or you just have the explicit expressions up to a certain $i$?

Comment: I don't know the formula for the $x_i$'s yet. $x[\tau]$ is to be plugged into a differential equation in order to determine these equations. (Grouping terms of powers of $\mu$.)

Comment: It sounds like you should be using something like `series[x_] := Sum[a[k] x^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]`, substitute it in the diff eq, and do some manual work to match up the coefficients and obtain some recursions. Then you can try `RSolve` on the recursions.

Comment: If it is really a poser series then might want to use something like `Series[x[t, mu], {mu, 0, n}]` where `n` is set to a positive integer of your liking.

Comment: @Daniel Is there a reasonably easy and automated way to carry out a procedure *similar* to the one described [here](http://www.math.psu.edu/papikian/Kreh.pdf)?  If I understand the question, this is what the OP is asking.  To me it seems that some steps (matching coefficients) are easier to do manually.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed. I'm a bit embarrassed at how simple the solution actually is, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [`GeneratingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeneratingFunction.html):

```
GeneratingFunction[a[n], n, τ]
```